# Little big query with loop?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, loops

I need to write a query in stored procedure, i miss the loop part below otherwise Insert and Select are correct, pls suggest to complete the query or alternate suggestions.

Passing inside as Parameter are @date,@sectn only

```
SELECT    Name  FROM    tblProductionEffcyDetails where wDate=@date and section =@sectn
```

I get list of  Names (example 5 names)

Loop 1 : For each Name I need to do below

Loop 2:

```
SELECT  Tstdmin,TAvlbmin,@name=Name, @eid=Empid
FROM tblProductionEffcyDetails
WHERE   (wDate = @date) AND (Section = @sectn) and Name = (1st name from the above query list)
```

`@TSH = Tstdmin` (If One value exists in database further value it should not take )

```
@TAT+=TAvlbmin
```

Insert above values to another table

```
INSERT INTO tblDailyReport  (wdate, Section, Name, Empid, TAvlT, TstdH, DEfficiency)
VALUES   (@date,@sectn,@name,@eid,@TAT,@TSH,(@TSH/@TAT))
```

Name, Empid are taken from tblProductionEffcyDetails.

Above in loop2  till all the same Name completes, once it is completed it goes to Loop1 and complete all names.

tblProductionEffcyDetails has many Names and repeating Names so all need to be in Loop. Finally each name(without repeating) and sum details will be inserted to tblDailyReport.

front end -C# Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do all of that in one statement though you have more columns in `tblDailyReport` than you have values.

```
INSERT INTO tblDailyReport (wdate, Section, Name, Empid, TAvlT, TstdH, DEfficiency)
SELECT 
    wdate, 
    Section, 
    Name, 
    @eid AS Empid, 
    SUM(Tstdmin) AS TAvlT, 
    SUM(TAvlbmin) AS TstdH,
    <Not Sure What you want here> AS DEfficiency
FROM tblProductionEffcyDetails
WHERE wDate = @date AND Section = @sectn 
GROUP BY wdate, Section, Name
```

Comment: This query is against the sql standard and will only run in mysql if full group by sql mode is **not** enabled. It is enabled by default in the newer versions of mysql.

Comment: @Shadow Are you saying that mysql doesn't allow for constants in a select when there is a group by, or in this case parameters?

Comment: @Shadow The more I read about ` ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` the more I'm convience that you're wrong as I do have all the columns in the select in the group by except for parameters which are not columns and thus not subject to that rule.  I'm also disturbed that mysql actually has a mode that allow you to select columns that are not in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a stored procedure for this, you can accomplish the whole thing in a single query using [insert ... select ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) query with joins and sum():

```
insert into tblDailyReport (wdate, Section, Name, Empid, TAvlT, TstdH, DEfficiency)
select wDate, Section, Name, empid, sum(TAvlbmin), sum(Tstdmin), sum(Tstdmin)/sum(TAvlbmin)
from tblProductionEffcyDetails
where wDate=@date and section =@sectn
group by wDate, Section, Name, empid
```

I have made 2 assumptions:

1. You have not disclosed how you want to treat empid, so I group by this field. You may have to change this based on your exact requirements.
2. You have not disclosed how you want to treat DEfficiency (it is completely missing from the insert query, so it has a syntax error), so I group by this field. You may have to change this based on your exact requirements.

Update:

Since DEfficiency is calculated as `@TSH/@TAT` in the updated question, you can calculate this field as `sum(Tstdmin)/sum(TAvlbmin)` (updated the query above).

Comment: The OP was inserting `@eid` into `Empid`, it's not really clear if they want that to come from the `tblProductionEffcyDetails` table or if that's just a value passed into the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot we are almost near to the solution, i have edited  the question to make it more understandable and cleared doubts, pls suggest

Comment: Updated the answer regarding DEfficiency. I'm still unclear on how you would like to use empid. I understand you get it from the same table as all other values, but you do not seem to use it in the summing up calculations, yet you insert its value in the result table. But,  you have enough information now how to solve the issue, so, pls make an attempt to complete the query yourself.

Comment: Almost same above two queries worked like Magic. Lots of Thanks to @Shadow and juharr.  One more suggestion will complete this.
Now we have data of wdate, Section, Name, Empid, TAvlT, TstdH, DEfficiency of a day. with this data i need to calculate for a month.
MonthlyEfficiency = sum of TstdH of particular month/sum of TAvlT of particular month

Pls suggest.

Comment: This is a different question from the current one, pls post it as a different question. However, if you paid attention to what we have suggested, then you should be able to resolve this 2nd question on your own, at least you could try to do it.

Comment: i have some idea but expected from masters. Thank You @Shadow.